# Customizing incollection layout in biblatex-dw

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-dw

I'm using the `biblatex-dw` package for my bibliography and have almost finished configuring it for my needs (or the university's needs, that is).

However, I still need to perform some small changes to adhere to the university guidelines. Specifically, I need to change the layout of the `@incollection` type.

What it currently looks like:
[image: current status]

What it should look like:
[image]

So, to summarize:

- `, in:` should be changed to `. In:`
- the positions of the fields `editor` and `title` need to be swapped
- instead of `(Hgg.)` (in case of multiple editors) or `(Hg.)` (in case of a single editor) after the editors name I want it to always read `hg. von <Editors name(s)>`

I already figured out how to achieve the first point by using 
`\renewbibmacro{in:}{. In:}`. However, I'm not sure if this is the "right" way to do this in biblatex.

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
            namefont=bold,
            firstnamefont=bold,
            firstfull=true,
            citeauthor=normalfont,
            editorstringfont=namefont,
            autocite=footnote,
            addyear=true]{biblatex}

% String modifications
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{phdthesis = {phil. Diss.}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{editors = {Hgg.}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{urlseen = {Datum des Zugriffs:}}

% Sort bibliography by last name
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\AtBeginBibliography{% change name delimiter from "," to "/" in bibliography
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@incollection{Metzler-Boheme,
    Title = {Bohème},
    Author = {Boerner, Maria-Christina},
    Booktitle = {Metzler Lexikon Literatur. Begriffe und Definitionen},
    Edition = {3., völlig neu bearb. Aufl.},
    Editor = {Burdorf, Dieter and Fasbender, Christoph and Moennighoff, Burkhard},
    Pages = {95},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Year = {2007}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource[]{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
   \nocite{*}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this is essentially a rather dull question: it's just a question of hacking the `incollection` driver, and a related macro. In this case, I'm afraid, hacking is the word -- I've adopted essentially *ad hoc* solutions to deal with an essentially *ad hoc* problem.

The only things I'd point out is that (1) I don't speak German so I hope I've got the relevant string right; (2) your example had the editors' names in ordinary type not bold, but your comment didn't draw attention to it as an issue. If you would rather have them in bold, remove the two `\renewcommand`s (and you can then get rid of the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother\ "guard" too; (3) any time you fiddle with a driver like this you may discover some corner case (no editor, just a translator or something) where it blows up, and you have to refine the driver.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-dw,
            namefont=bold,
            firstnamefont=bold,
            firstfull=true,
            citeauthor=normalfont,
            editorstringfont=namefont,
            autocite=footnote,
            addyear=true]{biblatex}

% String modifications -- we add also a modification for "by editor"
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{phdthesis = {phil. Diss.}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{editors = {Hgg.}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{urlseen = {Datum des Zugriffs:}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{byeditor = {hg\adddot\ von}}

% The only modification to this is to substitute one piece of punctuation
% and use our new bibmacro
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \ifbool{cbx:idemfull}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
     \ifnameundef{labelname}
       {}
       {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock}}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{authedxrefcheck}%
  \ifbool{cbx:authedxref}
    {\booltrue{xrefidem}}
    {\boolfalse{xrefidem}}%
  \ifbool{bbx:xref}
    {\iffieldundef{xref}
      {% Code, wenn kein xref vorhanden
       \usebibmacro{noxref:incollection}}
      {\printtext{\bbx@xref{\thefield{xref}}}% xref
       \usebibmacro{xrefvolume}%
       \usebibmacro{pages}}}%
    {\usebibmacro{noxref:incollection}}% bei xref=false
    \usebibmacro{finentry}}

 % Here we simply eliminate the original call to print editors, and
 % substitute one later -- but we hackily redefine the name font within
 % a group to prevent the names being bold
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro{noxref:incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit
  {\renewcommand\bbx@namefont{}%
   \renewcommand\bbx@firstnamefont{}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}%
  \ifbool{bbx:seriesbeforeedition}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{edition}%
  \usebibmacro{volumes+volume+part}%
  \ifbool{bbx:seriesstandard}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \ifbool{bbx:seriesafteryear}
    {\setunit{\addspace}%
     \usebibmacro{series+number}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}}
\makeatother

% Sort bibliography by last name
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

\AtBeginBibliography{% change name delimiter from "," to "/" in bibliography
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{/}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{/}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@incollection{Metzler-Boheme,
    Title = {Bohème},
    Author = {Boerner, Maria-Christina},
    Booktitle = {Metzler Lexikon Literatur. Begriffe und Definitionen},
    Edition = {3., völlig neu bearb. Aufl.},
    Editor = {Burdorf, Dieter and Fasbender, Christoph and Moennighoff, Burkhard},
    Pages = {95},
    Publisher = {Metzler},
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Year = {2007}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource[]{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
   \nocite{*}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A bibliography entry]

Comment: You could use the standard `in:` macro if you put a `\setunit{\addperiod\space}%` in front of it and not an `\adddot`. `\adddot` will typeset an 'abbreviation dot', while `\addperiod` sets a full stop. The punctuation tracker continuous   in midsentence  mode after the former, but changes to beginsentence after the latter.

Comment: So I could! I'd forgotten `addperiod`. It's been so long since I last wrote one of these things.

Comment: Yet still you came up with a great answer quickly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for! Much appreciated :-)